# iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

Tags: ssh, iptables, block

I was dumb enough and just executed:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

This blocks everything of course :)

Is there any hope for me to somehow still connect to the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have to either get access to the console, have someone else use console access, or reboot the server, assuming nothing saved your new iptables setting.

Comment: wow, thanks!!! i thought i ruined it. reboot really worked :)

Comment: Then remember when you have the rules you want in place you need to save the rules. Look up distro-specific ways to do it...some have scripts to auto-add them for bootup. Others don't.

Answer (score 4):

Use keyboard and screen, serial port, remote KVM, virtual serial port to VM host, or some other such recovery mechanism. Otherwise reboot.

Comment: how can I accept also your answer together with Bart's?